# How can I modify a Jenkins job environment variable value using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

Im using the Groovy Postbuild plugin and trying to modify an exists job environment variable as to some test Im running on the jobs log:

```
def map = ["x":"", "y":"", "z":""]

map.each{
it.value = (manager.getLogMatcher("$it.key(.*)\$")).toString().split(':')[1]
}

if(map.get('X') == ""){
 job_environment_variable = FOO
}
else {
 job_environment_variable = BOO
}
```

Comment: Try this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12721531/3843828

Comment: Thank you. already did that and Im trying to append action and not creating new one: Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa)