# Set Jenkins Environment variables via Groovy script

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, ansible

I'd like to set Jenkins Global Properties - Environment variables  via Groovy script (YAML file) which is executed in Ansible.
I've tried following

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
envVars.put("FOO1", "bar1")
envVars.put("FOO2", "bar2")
instance.save()
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413936/creating-a-jenkins-environment-variable-using-groovy or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins/10626193#10626193

Comment: Thank you for reply, but this I've seen already and this will not help.

Comment: Where is the YAML?

Answer (score 7):

Done in this way:

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)

envVars = null
if ( envVarsNodePropertyList == null || envVarsNodePropertyList.size() == 0 ) {
  newEnvVarsNodeProperty = new hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty();
  globalNodeProperties.add(newEnvVarsNodeProperty)
  envVars = newEnvVarsNodeProperty.getEnvVars()
} else {
  envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()  
}
envVars.put("name", "value")
instance.save()
```

Comment: i dont want  to set the variables globally, only for that build that time so instead of globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties() what can be used and what other changes do i need to make?