# Build Pipeline using a Branch Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I seem unable to create a Jenkins Pipeline job that builds a specific branch, where that branch is a build parameter.

Here's some configuration screenshots:

[image: param config]
(i've tried with a Git Parameter and a String Parameter, same outcome)

[image: branch config]
(I've tried `$BRANCH_NAME_PARAM`, `${BRANCH_NAME_PARAM}` and `${env.BRANCH_NAME_PARAM}`, same outcome for all variations)

[image]

And the build log:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/${BRANCH_NAME_PARAM}:refs/remotes/origin/${BRANCH_NAME_PARAM} --prune" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${BRANCH_NAME_PARAM}

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1970)
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong - any ideas on what?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-28447

Appears that its something to do with a lightweight checkout. if i deselect this option in my config, my parameter variables are resolved

Comment: That seems like a bug?

Comment: Following the links it looks like it was fixed a long time ago but broken more recently. This is the current ticket https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42971

Answer (score 11):

a bit more detailed with examples combined with VonC answer

**1**. Configure extended choice parameter named BRANCH:

- specify delimiter
- specify groovy script or path to groovy file:

> ```
> def command = "git ls-remote -h $gitURL"
> def proc = command.execute()
>
> proc.waitFor()         
>
> if ( proc.exitValue() != 0 ) {
>    println "Error, ${proc.err.text}"
>    System.exit(-1)
> }     
>
> def branches = proc.in.text.readLines().collect {
> it.replaceAll(/[a-z0-9]*\trefs\/heads\//, '') 
> }   
> return branches.join(",")
> ```

[image]

**2**. Set Branches to build: $BRANCH

[image]

**3**. Disable "Lightweight checkout" checkbox in the "Pipeline" secton of Jenkins job configuration:

[image]

Otherwise job will fail with following message:"stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${BRANCH"}"

**4**. Build with parameter executes groovy script and you will then get a dropdown list of branches

Comment: Nice! I was looking for that groovy script. +1

Comment: Isn't this what the Git Parameter Plugin already gives you? I get a drop down for my current jobs with a list of all the branches

Comment: Hi @Igor Rabkin

I have followed above instructions and it pull the branch list from Git and I have disabled the Lightweight checkout but I still get the error you mentioned. 

Do you know why?

Comment: Can you help me?? @Hopetds

Comment: @Kanth, It should work... check your configuration again

Answer (score 6):

I have tried the above solution but it didn't work for me. I have chosen a slightly different approach. I am posting because it will help someone in future.

1. Goto configures the pipeline job.
2. Check the option "This project is parameterized"
3. Add git paramter.
   Note: If it doesn't show the option, please goto manage plugins and install git parameter plugin.
4. My pipeline Configure looks like
   [image]
5. Uncheck lightweight checkout and update the "branch to build" in pipeline section.
   [image]
6. Save the configuration.

Comment: I dont have the option "Git Parameter". Why? Searching for a plugin yields "Plugin Page not Found". https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/

Answer (score 0):

Each time I had a job based on a branch, I had to put a [groovy script with EnvInject plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936515/6309) in order to remove the ref/heads part of the git branch selected in parameters.

If you keep `refs/heads/xxx`, Jenkins will look for the branch `ref/heads/ref/heads/xxx`.