# Jenkins Share common environment variables in a groovy method

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am building a declarative JenkinsFile, I have some common variables that I want to be shared across some Jenkins projects and jobs. 
So I created a jenkins shared library, but for some reason i can't get my Jenkins file to to read the common environment variables from common groovy.

```
pipeline {
   environment {
      commonEnv()
      Email_Notification_Enabled="true"
      Slack_Notification_Enabled="false"
   }
}
```

and in my groovy i had:

```
def call() {
    a = "abc"
    b = "abc"
}
```

It throws error that commonEnv() is not allowed in environments.
What is the possible way to achieve such behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a Groovy method that sets the common environment variables. Please refer this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10413936/6350321) to know how to do this. Include that method in Jenkins pipeline shared library.

Now call this Groovy method in declarative pipeline of each of your jobs. Remember that in a declarative pipeline, you may use Groovy only inside the `script` step. So, your pipeline would look something like:

```
    pipeline {    
        stages {    
            stage("First stage") {      
                steps {
                    script {
                        // call to Groovy method that sets environment variables
                    }                        
                    // other steps
                }
             }
             // other stages
        }
    }
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to have environment variables that are shared across all Jenkins projects and jobs, you should set them up on Jenkins **instance** level rather than on a Jenkins **project** or **job** level. 
So, instead of doing it in a Jenkinsfile (which will do it at Jenkins job level), I will do it in **Manage Jenkins** > **Configure System** > **Global properties** > **Environment Variables**:

[image: Jenkins]

The environment variables could then be read in the pipeline script from [Jenkins Global Variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference) **env**:

```
echo "This is my Jenkins global environment variable ${env.MY_ENV_VAR_NAME}"
```

Comment: Our Jenkins contain thousand of jobs for over 1000 repo, so setting it on a Jenkins level might affect other already defined jobs for other projects.

Comment: Earlier your question said "all Jenkins projects" and for that I provided this answer. Now that it says "some Jenkins projects", please see my second answer. Cheers !