# How to configure the application.properties externally in the Jenkins maven job?

Tags: java, spring, azure, maven, jenkins

I have a Springboot project and I'm trying to deploy it to the Azure web app via Jenkins job. Created maven project in Jenkins for compiling, testing, and deploying the projects are in the below name.

1. **CheckoutandBuild** project - here I configured my bitbucket which has my source code. this job just fetches the source code and executes the maven command *clean compile*
   Note: due to security I don't commit my `application.properties` to the bitbucket branch.
2. **UnitTest** project - based on the stable build of the CheckoutandBuild project, this job will execute the maven command *test*. I'm getting the below error while executing this project

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'azureADUtils': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'azure.openid.config.url' in value "${azure.openid.config.url}"
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'azure.config.url' in value "${azure.config.url}".
```

It is clearly saying it is expecting the value `${azure.config.url}` which is available in my `app.properties` which I haven't committed in bitbucket.

Then how can I configure the properties file in Jenkins to make the build successful? I tried adding the `app.properties` in ***Manage Jenkins->Managed files*** of Jenkins, But it is not taking my properties file.

How to add and configure my `app.properties` in the Jenkins job? is there any other way to add my properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Jenkins variable in application properties file of spring boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880497/using-a-jenkins-variable-in-application-properties-file-of-spring-boot-app)

Comment: Thanks for reply DeepDave. Actually we commit  spring boot proj to bitbucket except  app.prop. I want to configure this app.prop in my jenkins job separately. because my job while executing maven test command throwing an error "Could not resolve placeholder 'azure.config.url' in value "${azure.config.url}"". azure.config.url value available in app.prop file.In eclipse it is working because  i have app.prop in src/main/resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy your managed files to your build in Jenkins like this [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/) suggests.

By IMO you should reconsider your approach, the property file is an integrated part of the project. Does your entire property file is sensitive? Perhaps you could just leave the sensitive  values with an environment variable placeholder, like this:

```
non-sensitive-property=value1234
sensitive-property=${MY_ENV_VAR}
```

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your property while executing mvn command on Jenkins, considering you are using mvnw / mvn:

```
./mvnw  spring-boot:run \
 -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--azure.config.url=https://url"
```

Or

```
./mvnw  spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="\
 -Dazure.config.url=https://url"
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.